# Basic VBA Code (dlookup)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new to VBA and need help getting a command to work.  I need to have 2 valued looked up and a new record created when a button is pushed.  I am have issues with the dlookup.

```
Private Sub Add_Record_Click()
Dim db As Database
Dim r As Recordset
Dim x As Integer

Set db = CurrentDb
Set r = db.OpenRecordset("Copy Of Employee Work Statistics")

Y = r.Fields("School")
z = r.Fields("School Id")

Y = DLookup(Table![Routes].School, Table![Routes], "Route" = Table![Routes].[Route Name])
z = DLookup("school ID", "Customer Database", "school" = Y)

r.Update

DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`DLookup("school ID", "Customer Database", "school" = Y)`

Your syntax is wrong, you should be including all of the criterion (3rd parameter) in the string, as follows:

`DLookup("[school ID]", "[Customer Database]", "[school] = '" & Y & "'")`

where `&` is used for string concatenation, and Y is your previously declared variable. I would also encourage you to use square brackets (`[`,`]`) when refering to a column or table name, in order to avoid any conflicts due to reserved words, or any funny errors due to the spaces in the names.

As for the update part, Y and z are mere variables. What I guess your intent was, was to directly update your recordset. Therefore:

```
r.Fields("School") = DLookup("[" & Table![Routes].School & "]", _
"[" & Table![Routes] & "]", "[Route] = '" & Table![Routes].[Route Name] & "'" )

r.Fields("School Id") = DLookup("[school ID]", "[Customer Database]", _
"[school] = '" & Y & "'")

r.Update
```